# Cosa significa 'fare la punta agli aghi'?

Tags: idioms

I simply want to know what the idiom 'fare la punta agli aghi' actually means....if you can help me.  I've been searching but can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Where did you read or hear it?

Answer (score 4):

Sembra un modo di dire locale:

> A Bologna si dice "fare la punta agli spilli". Significa essere minuziosi, meticolosi e puntigliosi al limite della pedanteria.

(In Bologna they say:  "to sharpen pins". It means being meticulous, meticulous and punctilious bordering on pedantry.)

([www.secsolution.com](https://www.secsolution.com/notizia.asp?id=5082))